# Should I approve valid backtick only edits?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I think they are too minor, therefore I tend to reject as too minor - they are taking place instead of more important edits in review queue. Am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are other blatant issues with the post (like atrocious spelling and grammar, or a vague title), the editor clearly wasn't paying attention - or was just trying to farm reputation - and so the edit should be rejected, and if you have time, you should use *Reject and Edit* to fix those issues. If there were only minor issues that weren't addressed (the editor missed one typo, or didn't adjust a finer point of grammar) and the edits **actually improve readability**, then you should approve it or, preferably, use *Improve Edit*.

Of course, if there are no other issues and the edits help, then approval is the way to go.

Comment: I never use reject and edit because it forbids me from explaining my rejection. Filling up review comments prevents many duplicate posts on meta. Instead I approve/reject then make consequent edit.

Comment: @TomášZato Community produces a custom rejection reason that says something like "the edit did not correct critical issues with the post."

Comment: +1, also for the emphasis on _actually improving readability_. A few editors seem to think that every keyword or identifier needs to be in backticks, just because it's code. This does not always improve readability.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing to ask yourself, is does the edit improve the readability of the post?

If it does, you should approve the edit.

I don't see why it being a minor edit should make a difference.

Comment: Well the 6 character limit is there for a reason, and I remember having few edits having rejected as insubstantial too.

Comment: Have a look at the edit to my answer. It is only a 6 character change and it clearly improved my answer.

Comment: I think you don't understand the point of the 6 character limit. It exists because (a) insignificant edits have to be reviewed and therefore cost time of 4 other people and (b) users get 2 rep points for an edit, so it better be worth it.